# Open SwiftUI View using custom URL

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

I am trying to open a new view be tapping on custom hyperlink in an AttribiutedString.
There you can find a [preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMRwt.png) of this view.
I am using SwiftUI to create this view so I can not rely on UITextView function:

`func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction)` ... which I regret because there would have been no problem at all.

I have tried using `.onOpenURL` modifier but it seems not to be called at all.
I was expecting that when user clicks certain link I could override the default behaviour if clicked URL would match with the one created by me...

```
private var hyperlinkText: some View {
        let firstURL = URL(string: "firstSCREEN=1")!
        let secondURL = URL(string: "secondSCREEN=2")!

        return TextLabelWithHyperlink(completeString: "After clicking %@ first screen should be displayed and when you click %@ the second one should be presented.",
                               urlStringArray: [ firstURL, secondURL ],
                               stringArray: ["this link", "this next text with my custom link "],
                               fontSize: Constants.BottomDescription.fontSize)
        .onOpenURL { url in
            if url == firstURL {
                // open first screen
            }
            if url == secondURL {
                // open second screen
            }
            else {
                // open url in browser
            }
        }
    }
```

I know that there is a way to do it with `.environment` modifier but it does not support iOS 14 which I need for this project.